# Error when creating HTTPs key and cert in prompt

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, strawberry-perl

Using Apache 2.2, SSL is configured. I am creating the key and temporary cert in command prompt. When I use

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
```

I am returned this output :

> WARNING: can't open config file:
>   z:/strawberry_libs/build/*2013Q3*_/ssl/openssl. cnf error on line -1
>   of C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\o
>   penssl.cnf

and then it creates the key.

So good and fine. The error is bothersome. Then I try to make the cert with

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

Now it shows an error and wont create it.

> C:\temp>openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr WARNING:
>   can't open config file:
>   z:/strawberry_libs/build/*2013Q3*/ssl/openssl.cnf Unable to load
>   config info from z:/strawberry_libs/build/*2013Q3*/ssl/openssl.cnf

Not exactly sure how to proceed at this point as I can't get past this step for my assignment without the certification. If there is another way, or a way to correct the error that would be great.